# PageBlockTable - multiple content in the same popup issue

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, inline, popup

I am using PageBlockTable with inlineEdit support

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Bookings" id="bookings" >
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="scroll">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!bookings}" var="booking" onRowClick="selectBooking(this);" styleclass="floatingHeaderTable">

                <apex:column onClick="getBookingObjectBySelection('{!booking.Conf_No__c}');">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Confirmation Number" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="bookings">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="Conf_No__c" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>

                    <apex:outputField value="{!booking.Conf_No__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column onClick="getBookingObjectBySelection('{!booking.Conf_No__c}');">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink value="Priority Booking" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                            <apex:param name="sortField" value="lastName" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!booking.COB_Current_State__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                ................
                ................
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

When I double click on a filed which is a TextArea or a Dependent pick list , I am seeing a popup like below.

[image]

But sometimes there are multiple items on the same popup. Seems the filed I edited before stays there in the popup even after I edit another column. like below

[image]

Seems like an issue. It is very random. And sometimes values are not getting saved to the fields. Is there any way to avoid this? Any sfdc javascript functions I can call to clear the pop up ? Please help.

Comment: what the solution for this?